# Заполнить значения столбца значениями этого же столбца по условию с составным ключом

Tags: sql, join

Есть таблица:

```
||product_id||attribute_id||language_id||text              ||
| 68        | 22          | 1           | Натуральная кожа  |
| 68        | 22          | 2           | Натуральная кожа  |
| 168       | 23          | 1           | Искусственная кожа|
| 168       | 23          | 2           |                   |
| 168       | 32          | 1           | Картон            |
| 168       | 32          | 2           |                   |
| 681       | 12          | 1           | Бумага            |
| 681       | 12          | 2           |                   |
```

В некоторых строках для `language_id=2` нет значения `text`.

Нужно составить SQL-запрос, который заполнит поле `text` (`language_id=2`) значением из поля `text` (`language_id=1`).

Для JOIN нужно использовать составной ключ `product_id, attribute_id`.

Comment: А зачем вы вообще храните строки с lang=2, если их текст равен тексту для lang=1. Удалите их. А выборку, там где она нужна, делайте с `where lang in(1,2) order by lang desc limit 1`

Answer (score 2):

Заполнять значения столбца из другого столбца не нужно. Не стоить хранить редундантные данные.

Удалите записи, которые содержут пустые значения. Делайте выборку как советует [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693936/sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-join-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87#comment1027010_693936):

```
where lang in(1,2) order by lang desc limit 1
```

Или просто создайте представление, которое к каждой отсутствующей записи вернёт запись со значением по умолчанию (`language_id=1`). Как-то так:

```sql
delete from prodtext where text is null;

create or replace view prodtextall as 
select t.*, 'y' stored
from prodtext t
union all 
select * from ( 
    select product_id, attribute_id, id language_id, text, 'n'
    from prodtext cross join languages  
    where language_id = 1) l 
where not exists (
    select 1
    from prodtext t 
    where t.product_id = l.product_id
    and t.attribute_id = l.attribute_id
    and t.language_id = l.language_id)
```

Результат (флаг `stored=n` покажет, что перевода ещё нет и взято значение по умолчанию):

```sql
select *
from prodtextall
where product_id=168 and attribute_id=23 and language_id=2
/
PRODUCT_ID ATTRIBUTE_ID LANGUAGE_ID TEXT                                S
---------- ------------ ----------- ----------------------------------- -
       168           23           2 Искусственная кожа                  n
```

---

[Тестовые таблицы и данные](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2908fc189278627ae351edec597e750d), чтобы попробовать примеры выше.

Answer (score 1):

```
update table T1
set T1.TEXT = (select TEXT
               from table T2
               where T2.PRODUCT_ID = T1.PRODUCT_ID and
                     T2.ATTRIBUTE_ID = T1.ATTRIBUTE_ID and
                     T2.LANGUAGE_ID = 1)
where T1.LANGUAGE_ID = 2 and (T1.TEXT = '' or T1.TEXT is NULL)
```

Так, нет?

Comment: да, похоже. А как для mysql будет?
You can't specify target table 'T1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: алиасы для MySQL, по моему, указываются через `as`. попробуйте так

Comment: Не, в MySQL такой синтаксис невозможен, в подзапросе в принципе нельзя обращаться к таблице, которая обновляется. только join

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без вложенных запросов будет работать быстрее:

```
UPDATE attributes l2
   SET text = l1.text
FROM attributes AS l2
JOIN attributes AS l1 ON l1.attribute_id = l2.attribute_id
                         AND l1.product_id = l2.product_id
WHERE l2.language_id = 2
      AND l1.language_id = 1
      AND (l2.text = '' OR l2.text IS NULL)
      AND (l1.text != '' OR l2.text IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для MySql у меня получилось вот так:

```
UPDATE oc_product_attribute AS T1
JOIN oc_product_attribute AS T2 ON ( T2.PRODUCT_ID = T1.PRODUCT_ID
AND T2.ATTRIBUTE_ID = T1.ATTRIBUTE_ID )
SET T2.text = T1.text
WHERE T1.language_id = 1
AND T2.text = ""
```